# Why are spaces not allowed in tag names?

Tags: discussion

Per the help documents, "Spaces are not allowed in tags". Out of curiosity, what is the rationale behind this decision?

Comment: Just my thinking — tags are terminated when you press the spacebar in the tag editor. Obviously that's a conflict.

Comment: we use `-` for separation. I guess the space will cause a big issue for implementation

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62074/why-do-the-tags-have-a-dash-in-place-of-a-space

Answer (score 19):

If you want to specify a list of tags there has to be a separator between them.

In this case Stack Overflow chose the space character.

If you wanted to allow spaces in tags you'd have to either add quotes to the tag names:

> "this is a tag" this-is-also-a-tag another_tag

or use something else like a comma as the separator:

> this is a tag, this is also a tag, another tag

I don't know for sure but I assume that the thinking was that quoting tags or using a comma was thought to be too confusing and it'd be easier to explain and for people to use if space was the separator and there was a "no spaces in tags" rule.

Answer (score -10):

Tags (always in small letters) are defined to help for search and distinguish functionality.

Hyphen(-) character is used to denote separation between two words and same character is for (-) also & no conflicts is occurred yet using same for spaces and hyphen.

e.g. tag `ruby-on-rails` is used for `Ruby on Rails`

Comment: That doesn't answer the why.